# Soap API to get landingpage or microsite?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Is it possible to get LandingPage returned from SFMC SOAP API?

from the documentation, looks like none of the methods are supported(eg. Retrieve, Create, Update)?

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/landingpage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but if your Landing Pages just retrieves a content area by name, then you can interact with the [Content Area](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/exacttarget_for_appexchange_api_guide/objects/contentarea/) via SOAP API.  The set-up might look something like this:

**Landing Page**

```
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\landingPages\page1")=%%
```

**Page1 Content Area**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>Whee!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you Adam, the landing pages I am trying to access are not content areas, but thank you for the tip. I can get the microsite folder object via API, just not be able to list and cast the objects inside the folder into LandingPage object

Comment: It's really easy to turn them into Content Areas and they API the heck out of them. No one on our team has had any luck with the Microsoite or LandingPage API objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this **should** be supported as `LandingPage` is a valid ObjectType, but no methods appear to work with this object, which is frustrating.